# grails template Method code is too large error?

Tags: templates, grails, groovy

if Grails Template size is too big and using more g:tags than it fails to compile by template engine raise  an error Method code is too large ?

Comment: Could you paste a stacktrace and example code? Which version of Grails are you using? Unfortunatelly I'm not sure what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the template size is too large and having an error method code is too large and multiple compilation error in your gsp run than divide the _form template in to the multiple template like for example
if form have multiple section in body for example application details,candidate details, experience, reason to change, etc than create like

devide the form code (_form.gsp)

```
_candidate.gsp
_experience.gsp 
_reasonToChange.gsp
```

now the actual code is like inside the form template _form.gsp

```
<g:render template="candidate"></g:render>
<g:render template="experience"></g:render>
<g:render template="reasonToChange"></g:render>
```

now if you render the _form than complete form is render and having no problem in compilation and no error

in create.gsp you only render the form template

```
        <g:render template="form"/>
```

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with code blocks within GSPs. I seem to recall the maximum size is about 65,432 lines of code per block. The easy way around this is to use a comment within your GSP. This creates a new code block and segments your GSP code blocks. For example:

```
<%
// example comment
%>
```

Comment: yes segmenting the form template into multiple template is solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs due to the properties files if properties files are running under the loop or unable to compile properly due to error than this error will happen 
Multiple compilation

once you fixed the i18 properties files this problem is fixed
you can also use the

```
${message(code:'menu.home.label',default:'Home')} instead of
<g:message code="menu.home.label" default="Home"/>
```